# extract column from CSV file and add the column using filename and column number in argument

Tags: perl, csv, unix, scripting

I wrote a script to extract the two column; first is the column entered by the user in argument and second column is the next column to the first one; Now I have to perform addition of the columns separately.

Please note the file is a CSV file and has the string as heading of coloumns

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = $ARGV[0];
my $coloumn_number = $ARGV[1];
my $addition = 0;
my $sum = 0;
open(my $filedata, '<', $file) or die "Can't read file '$file'\n";
while (my $line = <$filedata>) {
    chomp $line;
        my @fields = split(",", $line);
         print "$fields[$coloumn_number],";
         print "$fields[$coloumn_number+1]\n";
         $sum += $fields[$coloumn_number];
         $addition += $fields[coloumn_number+1];

          }
print "$sum";
print "$addition";
```

When I run this script I get the error

```
-bash-4.1$ ./script1.pl /diff2.csv 2
Bareword "coloumn_number" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./script1.pl line 17.
Execution of ./script1.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

when I run the script without the last 5 lines of addition part it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You missed `$` in `$addition += $fields[coloumn_number+1];`. Should be `$addition += $fields[$coloumn_number+1];`

Comment: Sorry it might be a typo ! but still when I run the program it gets `Argument "SITE ENGINEERS 2" isn't numeric in addition (+) at ./script1.pl line 16, <$filedata> line 1.
Argument "ELECTRICIANS" isn't numeric in addition (+) at ./script1.pl line 17, <$filedata> line 1.
30,13
26,12
30,19
30,14
26,18
22,20
23,12
20,16
29,16
23,17`

It still does not let me print the addition because of the string heading of column

Comment: input file would be really helpful

Comment: here is the input `WEEK,SITE ENGINEERS,SITE ENGINEERS 2,ELECTRICIANS,ELECTRICIANS 2,ON SITE INSPECTORS,ON SITE INSPECTORS 2,CRANE OPERATOR,CRANE OPERATOR 2
ONE,16,30,13,24,19,20,17,22
TWO,15,26,12,29,19,30,20,27
THREE,13,30,19,21,16,25,19,20
FOUR,16,30,14,25,18,24,15,26
FIVE,12,26,18,29,16,23,12,26
SIX,15,22,20,20,13,27,14,20
SEVEN,13,23,12,21,15,21,18,28
EIGHT,16,20,16,23,12,22,18,20
NINE,14,29,16,28,15,28,16,28
TEN,17,23,17,28,14,30,17,20`

Comment: It seems to be one line. Is it correct? And `$fields[$column_number]` contains exactly `'SITE ENGINEERS 2'` for `$column_number == 2`.

Comment: Input file is just looks like e


`WEEK,SITE ENGINEERS,SITE ENGINEERS 2,ELECTRICIANS,ELECTRICIANS 2,ON SITE INSPECTORS,ON SITE INSPECTORS 2,CRANE OPERATOR,CRANE OPERATOR 2
ONE,16,30,13,24,19,20,17,22
TWO,15,26,12,29,19,30,20,27
THREE,13,30,19,21,16,25,19,20
FOUR,16,30,14,25,18,24,15,26
FIVE,12,26,18,29,16,23,12,26
SIX,15,22,20,20,13,27,14,20
SEVEN,13,23,12,21,15,21,18,28
EIGHT,16,20,16,23,12,22,18,20
NINE,14,29,16,28,15,28,16,28
TEN,17,23,17,28,14,30,17,2`

Comment: Yeah, OK, but I don't see any new lines here. Please update your question with two-three lines from your file. It is really hard to understand what do you have for input.